# SQL Server nvarchar to money/decimal conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

I have a `nvarchar` column in SQL Server table that stores dollar amounts along with the cents values but without any separator to distinguish the cents. For ex: `$123.47` is being stored as `12347`. The last two digits in the `nvarchar` column specify the cents value.

When I use

```
Convert(money, field)
```

it is returning `$12347.00`. But what I need is `$123.47`.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divide by 100.

```
Convert(money, field) / 100
```

**Try These Formats if you want :**

[MonyFormat](http://sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/moneyformat/)